# Problem implementing ActionListener to a group of jButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

i have a problem implementing ActionListener on a group of 10 jButtons. Each button has its text property set to a digit, from 0 - 9. So jButton1 will have its text property set to 1, JButton2 will have 2 as its text, ...., .... then jButton9 will have its text set to 9. When i click any of those buttons, i want to append the value of its text property to a JTextField.

The problem am getting is every time i click a button, the value of its text property is printed twice, some times thrice some even four times, it just happens randomly.

For example, if i click a button with text 4 once, i can get 44 printed in the JTextField, if i then click 7 only once again, i can end up with 4477 or even 447777. below is my code

```
 public class tCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public tCalculator(){
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);
        btn4.addActionListener(this);
        btn5.addActionListener(this);
        btn6.addActionListener(this);
        btn7.addActionListener(this);
        btn8.addActionListener(this);
        btn9.addActionListener(this);
        btnZero.addActionListener(this);
          } 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        String x = txtArea.getText();
        String k = evt.getActionCommand();
        String a = x + k ;
        txtArea.setText(a);

    }}

private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        ActionListener actionListener = new tCalculator();
        btn1.addActionListener(actionListener);

    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Please try to reproduce the problem with just a couple of buttons, not 10.

Comment: BTW - those code snippets read like complete nonsense.  Where are the buttons instantiated?  Why does the `actionPerformed()` create an entire new GUI?  After doing that, why is the new (invisible) GUI added to btn1 (only) as a listener?  The level of misunderstanding shown even in those snippets indicates you should be coding simpler things than GUIs for the moment.

Comment: *"..here is the complete code."* `F:\..\JFrame1.java:63: illegal start of expression
   public class tCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   ^
1 error`  Given this code does not compile, the reports of run-time errors must be exaggeration.  Again, but louder this time **For better help sooner, post an SSCCE.**

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: we learn from mistakes. Peter Lang has posted a solution, but thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `btn1ActionPerformed` adds another `ActionListener`. We do not see where it is called, but this would explain your problem. Whenever you click the button, you have one more `Listener` which is executed at the next click.

Looks like this code was generated by an IDE. Remove that action there and your code should work.

---

**EDIT:**

1. Remove the Actions in your IDE
2. Remove the constructor of `tCalculator` and put the code into the constructor of `JFrame1` (below `initComponents`.

```
...
initComponents();
ActionListener actionListener = new tCalculator();
btn1.addActionListener(actionListener);
btn2.addActionListener(actionListener);
....
```

These steps ensure that your Listener is registered exactly once per button.

BTW:

1. It does not make sense for `tCalculator` to extend `JFrame`. Remove that.
2. Class names start with an upper-case letter (`TCalculator`). A better name could be `ButtonActionListener` or something like that.

Comment: I don't see where btn1ActionPerformed is called.

Comment: @Giann: Looks like `btn1ActionPerformed` is generated by an IDE, so I assume that it is called in some generated `Listener` that we don't see here.

Comment: Peter, are you implying that btn1ActionPerformed is not required?, because if i comment out the code in btn1ActionPerformed, then nothing  is displayed in the JTextField no matter which button i click!!

Comment: True, btn1ActionPerformed is generated by the IDE

Comment: @Name.IsNullOrEmpty: Looks like we need to see your complete code. If `tCalculator` is the `JFrame` that you are displaying, then the constructor is called and your listeners are added. The problem you describe now would mean, that the constructor is not called before, but only within `btn1ActionPerformed`. That's why it does not work when you comment it out.

Comment: @Peter: *"..Instead of using setText, try append."*  Although not mentioned in the code snippets, the OP states they are using a `JTextField` which, unlike `JTextArea`, has no `append(String)` method. *"Looks like we need to see your complete code."*  I don't, just an SSCCE will be fine.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Thanks! For some reason I thought that this was a `JTextArea` - edited my post. And yes, a SSCCE would be great, it might even be a chance for the OP to find the problem. Guess I've been here to long to hope for things like that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> it is because you have just assigned
>   the action listener to your button
>   with this and on method you'r again
>   assigining the action listener which
>   is the instance of tCalculator class
>   so when you press the button boath
>   action listener called and 2 results
>   are shown to you, just remove the
>   btn1ActionPerformed method and it will
>   work fine. try below code now................................

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Tcalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JButton btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9,btnZero;
    private JTextField txtArea;

    public Tcalculator(){
        btn1 = new JButton("1");
        btn2 = new JButton("2");
        btn3 = new JButton("3");
        btn4 = new JButton("4");
        btn5 = new JButton("5");
        btn6 = new JButton("6");
        btn7 = new JButton("7");
        btn8 = new JButton("8");
        btn9 = new JButton("9");
        btnZero = new JButton("0");
        txtArea = new JTextField(15);
        init();
          } 

    //performed all gui operations
    public void init(){

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(200, 200);
        add(txtArea);
        add(btn1);add(btn2);
        add(btn3);add(btn4);
        add(btn5);add(btn6);
        add(btn7);add(btn8);
        add(btn9);add(btnZero);

        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);
        btn4.addActionListener(this);
        btn5.addActionListener(this);
        btn6.addActionListener(this);
        btn7.addActionListener(this);
        btn8.addActionListener(this);
        btn9.addActionListener(this);
        btnZero.addActionListener(this);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    // i am using this your made function nothing changed
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        String x = txtArea.getText();
        String k = evt.getActionCommand();
        String a = x + k ;
        txtArea.setText(a);

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new  Tcalculator();
    }

}
```

Comment: when i remove btn1ActionPerformed and click any button, nothing happens, no value is printed in the jTextField. Looks like i have to associate actionPerformed to my buttons in some way and am missing that part.

Comment: please check the code i have made this for you to understand well